# show error message after ng-repeat section

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have added a ng-repeat section in AngularJs. I hve added a required field validator. However, the page height increases when all the fields are emptied, as the span tag data shows up.. Is it possible to show only one error message after the ng-repeat section which describes the error. The current UI code is as below:

```
<div class="row" ng-if="selectedSeasonType">
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label class="form-group col-md-3">Language</label>
                        <label class="form-group col-md-4">Title</label>
                        <label class="form-group col-md-5">Description</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />



          <div class="row" ng-repeat="Descriptions in seasonsWithDescription" ng-if="selectedSeasonType">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2 top-Margin-language">
                        <label ng-model="Descriptions.Language">{{Descriptions.Language}}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 top-Margin-Title">
                        <input type="text" maxlength="150" class="form-control input-md" required="" name="titleValidate_{{$index}}" ng-model="Descriptions.Title" />
                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.titleValidate_{{$index}}.$error.required">Title is required</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                        <textarea maxlength="500" class="form-control input-md noresize" required="" name="descriptionValidate_{{$index}}" noresize="" ng-model="Descriptions.Description"></textarea>
                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.descriptionValidate_{{$index}}.$error.required">Description is required</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                        <a style="cursor:pointer">
                            <img ng-src="{{DeleteIcon_url}}" alt="delete image" ng-click="($index == !selectedDeleteIcon) || seasonsWithDescription.splice($index,1)" ng-class="{'disabled': $first}" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

How to add only one error message after the ng-repeat section to describe the required data in AngularJs?
Thanks

Comment: Can you add your own custom error msg after the ng-repeat section.

Comment: Hi, There are atleast 10 rows, which has title textbox and description textarea. I am not sure, how to show the error message. It can be either "Title" empty or "Description" empty or both empty.

Comment: See that's the thing. You need to be more specific with your questions. Let's just say you have "Title" right now. Do you want to show an error msg for each empty Title. Or do you want to show one error msg at the bottom, if one of the Titles is missing? In the former case, you will have to continue with what you are doing. In the latter, you need to have a custom error msg with ng-show/hide mechanism. One way is to have a counter for all non-empty titles. If the count is less than your repeat size, show error.

Comment: Hi @sisyphus.. could you please show a code example for the counter method.

Comment: Can you try [this plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/5sFIMIotzsW85Is0QTQO) . Avery rough one but demonstrates the idea. If this works for you, I will post it in the answer

Comment: Hi.. yes, it has the concept. However, when all the data are filled and submit button is clicked, still it shows the error message

Comment: You must not have refreshed from previous submit. It's just a rough example mate. Work it out. I have modified it a little again though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, here is a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/5sFIMIotzsW85Is0QTQO) to suit your need.

```
 $scope.isTitleMissing = false;

$scope.cars = [{id: 1, 'brand': 'Chevy', 'model': 'Camarro'},
{id: 1, 'brand': 'Ford', 'model': 'Mustang'},
{id: 1, 'brand': 'Hyundai', 'model': 'Santa Fe'},
{id: 1, 'brand': 'Honda', 'model': 'CRV'},
{id: 1, 'brand': 'BMW', 'model': '350'}]


$scope.submitForm = function(){

 var ctr = $scope.cars.length;
 var titleCtr = 0;
 for(var i = 0 ; i < ctr ; i++){
   if($scope.cars[i].title != null){
     titleCtr++;
   }
 }
//

if(titleCtr < ctr){
  $scope.isTitleMissing = true;
}else{
  //continue with submit
   $scope.isTitleMissing = false;
  // alert('Total cars - ' + ctr + ' and total Title '+ titleCtr);
}
```

It just has a count of total records and another one for total tiles count. If the latter is less than total records, it shows an error msg, else continues to submit.

Hope this helps.